# Password verify function not working all the time

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to verify an encrypted password but for some reason it is always invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

For example my password would be 'test' , so I do this:

```
$hash = '$2y$10$4Ed6XtU2E6qjzSOSUOA0xuBEA0sokTJMrDBH5ttgJzMVXSh0muoX.';
$password = 'test';

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

But password 'geheim123' does work with this hash:

```
$hash = '$2y$10$LY0l0pOc8vLCzI.VvxK3gOTlXoVwnP2dlAzicj9uE62Q39XfeTY/6';
$password = 'geheim123';

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

What can be the reason the second one works, but the other one doesn't?

This is where I encrypt my passwords:

```
$pass = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

Comment: Where are those hashes from?

Comment: I assume they come from `password_hash()` and OP is confusing hashes. using wrong hash on `test` @rustyx

Comment: it seems you password has no salt

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: the second password has a salt , thats why its okay

Answer (score 0):

it seems you "test" password has no salt.

re hash your password like

```
echo password_hash("test", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

this has given me this `$2y$10$4a8QVv3VZNnXpgbT66I1He6eHqYBj.N94GIS7yHMoEW2Eb1Eq003O` but you may get a new hash not this when you run that code. but it will still give the same valid status

```
    $hash = '$2y$10$4a8QVv3VZNnXpgbT66I1He6eHqYBj.N94GIS7yHMoEW2Eb1Eq003O';
$password = 'test';



if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!'; // okay
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Comment: I already do this, but for some reason one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Yes it works, but when I change it to work with my code (no hardcoded password, but a password that is posted through a form) it stops working.

Comment: try to use trim password before you can hash the password and trim the input password on verification like `trim($_POST['password'])` it seems your password has a white space in it